# How Can I solve this problem Programming with GTK+ on C++?

Tags: c++, gtk, gtk3, gtkmm, gtk2

I come to ask some things about gkt with the hope that someone can help me.
I am programming a graphical interface of another program where what I want is to put a drop list (in this case I put a combo box) and in the same code I am generating some random arrays(int array) that are generated infinitely with a while (-1) cycle, my question is, how can I update the combox or drop list(add elements) or a label with the array of each iteration?, and add one more element to the list and this element is the array generated previously? all this is in C ++ forgive the annoyance and thanks for your help! thank you

Or exist some way to convert a int, double, char string or another variable to a gchar?

Comment: Are you doing this in GTK or in gtkmm? You tagged gtkmm, but did not mention it in your question. Also, please tag only one version, the version actually used by your code.

Comment: To convert a number to a string (`gchar *`), you may use `g_strdup_printf`. There's probably a better, "C++" way to do it, but this C call should work. Don't forget to call `g_free` on that memory after use.